# What is the formula for Custom Responsive Grid Layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, media-queries

I would like to create my own responsive media query. I need that to be 16 grid layout. I know there is a formula and I can see some websites provides that. But I would like to know the exact formula, then I can clearly understand what and how it works. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: calculate your grid here http://gridcalculator.dk/

Comment: actually youe need to divide 100 / 16  where 16 is your total grid

Comment: @IsmailFarooq thanks for the URL, I would like to know how they set the Gutter spaces.

Comment: its better to see any framework check its css file. my suggestion check bootstrap css file how they design there frameworks for now see here http://gridcalculator.dk/#/1170/12/30/0

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support? That would change how you make your grid, with or without flexboxes.